# LINQ TO XML Update WIX PATCH File

Tags: c#, wix, linq-to-xml

Give the following XML I'm trying to update the UpgradeImage and TargetImage SourceFile attributes respectively using Linq to XML.  Is there an issue with the way this XML is formed or am I just completely missing something?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<PatchCreation
  Id="224C316C-5894-4771-BABF-21A3AC1F75FF"
  CleanWorkingFolder="yes"
  OutputPath="patch.pcp"
  WholeFilesOnly="yes">
<PatchInformation
    Description="Update Patch"
    Comments="Update Patch"
    ShortNames="no"
    Languages="1033"
    Compressed="yes"
    Manufacturer="me"/>

<PatchMetadata
    AllowRemoval="yes"
    Description="Update Patch"
    ManufacturerName="me"
    TargetProductName="Update"
    MoreInfoURL="http://andrewherrick.com/"
    Classification="Update"
    DisplayName="Update Patch"/>

<Family DiskId="5000"
    MediaSrcProp="Sample"
    Name="Update"
    SequenceStart="5000">
  <UpgradeImage SourceFile="c:\new.msi" Id="PatchUpgrade">
    <TargetImage SourceFile="c:\old.msi" Order="2" Id="PatchUpgrade" IgnoreMissingFiles="no" />
  </UpgradeImage>
</Family>

<PatchSequence PatchFamily="SamplePatchFamily"
    Sequence="1.0.0.0"
    Supersede="yes" />
</PatchCreation>
</Wix>
```

Comment: I don't know anything about WiX, but it's hard to say what's wrong without seeing any of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you forgot to supply the namespace when querying

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi";

var doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\test.xml");
var ui = doc.Elements(ns + "Wix").Elements(ns + "PatchCreation").
                 Elements(ns + "Family").Elements(ns + "UpgradeImage").Single ();

ui.Attribute("SourceFile" ).Value = "c:\newer.msi";

doc.Save(@"C:\test2.xml");
```

**Edit**

An alternative is to use the XPathSelectElement extension method

```
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable()); 
mgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"); 
var el = doc.Root.XPathSelectElement("//ns:Wix/ns:PatchCreation/ns:Family/ns:UpgradeImage", mgr);
el.Attribute("SourceFile").Value = @"c:\evennewer.msi";
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [these xml extensions](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/blob/master/XElementExtensions.cs) try,

```
XElement wix = XElement.Load("file");
wix.Set("PatchCreation/Family/UpgradeImage/SourceFile", "new file path", true)
   .Set("TargetImage/SourceFile", "new file path", true);
```

The extensions will automatically get the namespace for you.  Set() returns the XElement of the element that the attribute was set on.  So the second Set() starts from the UpgradeImage element.