# How to match elements in XML - C#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm using a form to display XML elements. Every time I click on a module inside a listbox I want to display its `<Code>` value for instance, in a label on the form. The problem I'm having is that the way I've done it is that the XML is being read all at once, and I'm not able to, or don't know how to, search inside my XML file. So I think I just need a way to search in XML to find the `<Code>` element.

EDIT: Here is how far I am with trying to display the `<Code>` element in the label when it matches the `<Name>` element in the listbox:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var document = XDocument.Load(workingDir + @"\ModulesList.xml");

    var code = from d in document.Descendants("Name")
               where d.Value == listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
               select d.Parent.Element("Code").Value;

    labelCodeNumber.Text = code.ToString();

}
```

But the problem is that the labelCodeNumber doesn't display the value of `code`, it displays some weird collections stuff instead. Also I'm not sure if I am doing the output right i.e. `labelCodeNumber.Text = code.ToString();`

And here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SoftwareEngineering>
  <Module>
    <Name>Algorithms and Data Structures</Name>
    <Code>3SFE504</Code>
    <Capacity>5</Capacity>
    <Semester>1</Semester>
    <Prerequisite>none</Prerequisite>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Name>3D Graphics I</Name>
    <Code>3SFE508</Code>
    <Capacity>5</Capacity>
    <Semester>1</Semester>
    <Prerequisite>none</Prerequisite>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Name>Event-Driven Programming</Name>
    <Code>3SFE513</Code>
    <Capacity>10</Capacity>
    <Semester>1</Semester>
    <Prerequisite>none</Prerequisite>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Name>Object Oriented Design</Name>
    <Code>3SFE514</Code>
    <Capcity>10</Capcity>
    <Semester>1</Semester>
    <Prerequisite>none</Prerequisite>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Name>Requirements Engineering</Name>
    <Code>3SFE516</Code>
    <Capacity>10</Capacity>
    <Semester>1</Semester>
    <Prerequisite>none</Prerequisite>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Name>Introduction to AI</Name>
    <Code>3SFE599</Code>
    <Capacity>5</Capacity>
    <Semester>1</Semester>
    <Prerequisite>none</Prerequisite>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Name>Java Mobile Application Development</Name>
    <Code>3SFE540</Code>
    <Capacity>5</Capacity>
    <Semester>1</Semester>
    <Prerequisite>3SFE514(corequisite)</Prerequisite>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Name>C# .NET Programming</Name>
    <Code>3SFE541</Code>
    <Capacity>5</Capacity>
    <Semester>1</Semester>
    <Prerequisite>3SFE514(corequisite)</Prerequisite>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Name>Software Engineering Group Project</Name>
    <Code>3SFE515</Code>
    <Capacity>5</Capacity>
    <Semester>2</Semester>
    <Prerequisite>3SFE514(corequisite)</Prerequisite>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Name>Software Engineering</Name>
    <Code>3SFE519</Code>
    <Capacity>10</Capacity>
    <Semester>2</Semester>
    <Prerequisite>none</Prerequisite>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Name>Mobile User Interface Development</Name>
    <Code>3SFE542</Code>
    <Capacity>5</Capacity>
    <Semester>2</Semester>
    <Prerequisite>3SFE540</Prerequisite>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Name>Interactive Multimedia</Name>
    <Code>3MTS954</Code>
    <Capacity>5</Capacity>
    <Semester>2</Semester>
    <Prerequisite>none</Prerequisite>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Name>Concurrent Programming</Name>
    <Code>3SFE555</Code>
    <Capacity>5</Capacity>
    <Semester>2</Semester>
    <Prerequisite>none</Prerequisite>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Name>Mobile Gaming</Name>
    <Code>3SFE557</Code>
    <Capacity>10</Capacity>
    <Semester>2</Semester>
    <Prerequisite>none</Prerequisite>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Name>Intelligent Systems</Name>
    <Code>3SFE500</Code>
    <Capacity>10</Capacity>
    <Semester>2</Semester>
    <Prerequisite>3SFE599</Prerequisite>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Name>3D Graphics II</Name>
    <Code>3SFE501</Code>
    <Capacity>10</Capacity>
    <Semester>2</Semester>
    <Prerequisite>3SFE508</Prerequisite>
  </Module>
</SoftwareEngineering>
```

FINAL EDIT:
I figured it out! Thanks to Marcin and psubsee for their help and contribution. This code below goes in the listbox1_selectedindexchanged method

```
var code = from d in document.Descendants("Name")
           where d.Value == (String) listBox1.SelectedItem
           select d.Parent.Element("Code").Value;

foreach (var item in code)
{
    labelCodeNumber.Text = item.ToString();
}
```

Comment: See my answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933578/c-sharp-linq-to-xml-update-wix-patch-file/9933934#9933934

Comment: Similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933578/c-sharp-linq-to-xml-update-wix-patch-file/9933934#9933934 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951026/c-sharp-how-to-get-xml-elements-and-output-to-labels http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939567/how-to-read-from-xml-file-and-put-the-list-of-element-in-listview-on-the-form No one making his homework by himself?

Comment: @L.B I am! its just not working out, plus I told u I'm trying to do something different

Comment: @AZ1 don't worry man, our wise man has a mental problem already. It seems the way he talks is always like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change your concept and use XDocument instead of XmlReader:

```
var document = XDocument.Load(workingDir + @"\ModulesList.xml");
```

To fill up the listbox use something like that:

```
var items = From d in document.Descendants("Name")
            select d.Value;

foreach(var item in items)
    listBox1.Items.Add(item);
```

And then to find `<code>` from selected element you can make that kind of Linq to XML query:

```
var code = From d in document.Descendants("Name")
           where d.Value == SelectedName
           select d.Parent.Element("Code").Value
```

Comment: Sorry for my noobness, I looked at the documentation and couldn't find the right namespace to be able to use method Load and also From, Descendants etc. Could you kindly provide that? I tried using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq.XDocument;
using System.Xml.XmlDocument;

Comment: `var document = XmlDocument.Load(workingDir + @"\ModulesList.xml");` is incorrect.  The OP should be using `var document = XDocument.Load(workingDir + @"\ModulesList.xml");`

Comment: @AZ1 try `System.Xml.Linq`.  That is the name space for all of the Linq based classes for XML (XDocument, XElement, etc)

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks for the previous fix, I am using System.Xml.Linq but for some reason it won't recognize the key words such as 'where' and 'select'

Comment: @AZ1 this is why some people hate extension methods, as it can be confusing if you are not referencing the correct namespace.  Most of the Linq based methods are extension methods and do not reside as methods in the specific types.  `Select` and `Where` are actually part of the `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I'm using that as well :P hehe, I'm still looking through the documentation to try and find out

Comment: @AZ1 so this doesn't become a long back and forth discussion, if you want to try a Linq solution and need help, maybe you should update the question with your `Linq` code

Comment: @psubsee2003 - right. Should be XDocument. I edited my anwser.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - If I could please get a bit of your help, I'm trying to use your find the <Code> element bit that you posted in my listbox_selectedindexchanged method event as such: var code = from d in document.Descendants("Name")
                       where d.Value == listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
                       select d.Parent.Element("Code").Value;

Comment: I just don't know how to output it

Answer (score 5):

If you are reading it all at once then do not use an XmlReader.

Load it into an XDocument and you can use LINQ to find whatever you want.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);  // do this 1x

// untested
var names = doc.Root.Descendants("Module").Elements("Name").Select(e => e.Value);
listBox1.Items.AddRange(names);
```

Comment: That's why I said `//untested`. `AddRange(names.ToList())` might work, or as last resort a foreach loop.

Comment: I know I'm getting on everybody's nerves but I can't figure this stuff out. How do I construct a foreach? I tried foreach(XElement name in doc) but it said foreach cannot operate on type XDocument

Answer (score 0):

The points about using the Xml.Linq namespace are good ones because loading the data into an `XDocument` and querying the elements is much cleaner to look at and easier to maintain than the `XmlReader` code you are using.  If you ever change the format of your xml data or reuse the code in another method, it will be easier to update the query vs modifying the `XmlReader` code you have.  The only advantage to XmlReader would be if the XML is huge and you do not want to read it into memory all at once.

(But you said you wanted to be different)

The issue you are having with adding the values to the `ListBox` is related to the fact that `ListBox.Items.AddRange()` is expecting an object array and you are trying to pass `IEnumerable<String>`. You need to convert your IEnumerable to an array first, as in my [answer to another of your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9955256/250725) earlier

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(names.ToArray());
```