# Adding XML elements to ListBox

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, listbox

I don't know how to convert the type for name so that each element in it can be added to my ListBox. If someone could help that would be much appreciated.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(workingDir + @"\Moduleslist.xml");

var names = doc.Root.Descendants("Module").Elements("Name").Select(b => b.Value);

listBox1.Items.AddRange(names);
```

I'm getting an error on AddRange(names) saying invalid arguments

Comment: variable names is array or not...!

Comment: Is it a forms app, web forms, or what?

Comment: you can use addrange function only with array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

names is `IEnumerable<String>` and `listBox.Items.AddRange` is expecting an object array and there is no implicit cast between them.

A quick solution would be to:

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(names.ToArray());
```

or

```
foreach (var item in names)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude that works nicely, I've substituted that for my XmlTextReader code which populated the listbox instead. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this code instead of your last line of code:

```
listBox1.DataSource = names;
this.listBox1.DisplayMember = YOURDISPLAYMEMBER;
this.listBox1.ValueMember = YOURVALUEMEMBER;
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(doc.Root.Descendants("Module").Elements("Name").Select(b => b.Value).ToArray());
```